# ASP .NET MVC - getting null querystring values in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string

I'm trying to reach a controller method by providing some url parameters :

http://localhost/GoTo/Index?topic=test

Here's the method I want to reach :

```
    public ActionResult Index(string topic) 
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
```

Problem is, the topic parameter in the method is always null. I also tried to check what I got in Request.QueryString collection, but it's empty.

Any lead/explanation would be appreciated.

EDIT : Screenshot requested :

[image: UPDATE : Screenshot of the code as per requested]

Comment: Non-repro. If Request.QueryString is empty, the request didn't supply a query string. Are you sure you're debugging the correct request, and not a separate (AJAX?) request?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that I'm looking at the right request indeed.

Comment: Try to add `[FromUri] string topic` if it is old MVC or `[FromQuery]` for ASP.NET Core

Comment: _"I'm absolutely sure that I'm looking at the right request indeed"_ - and I'm sure you're not. Can you show a screenshot of what you're doing? This is pretty fundamental HTTP/ASP.NET stuff and you can be definitely sure ASP.NET isn't broken in this regard.

Comment: @CodeCaster here's the screenshot asked. Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Traffy can you please share code calling this method?

Comment: Is there any routing defined which is ignoring the query string?

Comment: @jishansiddique to be honest, for now I'm just calling the url through my browser. Didn't implement it yet somewhere else in the code.

Comment: convert the data type from string to int and send request with integer value like topic=1, the pipeline will through exception which may reveal the possible cause. Because string can silently take null, but int cannot.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath that might be the case indeed ! Thanks for the lead !

Comment: ok so please check this http://localhost/GoTo/?topic=test or change Index to some other action name and check it's worked

Comment: Check your RouterConfig.cs. There would probably be the paramter name as `id` instead of `topic` and type is int. And try to call it with URL as: localhost/GoTo/test

Answer (score 1):

Please try this it's working for me check below screenshot

[image]

Just call you're URL like this

```
http://localhost/GoTo?topic=test

public class TestingController : Controller
{
        // GET: Testing
        public ActionResult Index(string topic)
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```